# Embedding into a restricted direct product of finite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

Residually finite groups are those groups embeddable in a direct product of a family of finite groups. What happens if we consider only restricted direct product?

Comment: Subgroups of restricted direct products have very restrictive properties: they are locally finite, and they are FC-groups (i.e., all conjugacy classes are finite, or equivalently, every element has a centralizer of finite index). This restricts to locally finite residually finite FC-groups. Whether every such group embeds into a restricted direct product of finite groups, I don't see immediately.

Comment: These are locally finite FC-groups (the centralizer of every element has finite index. See "FC groups whose periodic parts can be embedded in direct products of finite groups" and references there.

Comment: @MarkSapir it can't be true, since there are (abelian) locally finite FC-groups that are not residually finite.

Comment: What cant be true?

Comment: @MarkSapir your comment looks like the assertion that groups that are (E) embeddable into restricted direct products of finite groups are exacty those locally finite FC-groups. Possibly you were just saying that groups (E) are locally finite FC-groups, in which case it's a trivial remark which doesn't need a reference.

Comment: The reference is to a paper where a description is given  and papers where the theory of FC groups is developed. There are books about the subjecr. Most of results are about connections between FC -groups and direct products of finite groups.

Comment: For example  Groups with Finite Conjugacy Classes
YM Gorchakov - 1978 - Nauka, Moscow

Comment: I don't actually know whether every residually finite abelian $p$-group $A$ embeds into a direct sum of finite (abelian) groups. For instance, what about the torsion subgroup of $\prod_n C_{p^n}$?

Comment: @Yves: direct sum of finite abelian groups is isomorphic to a direct sum of finite cyclic groups. Kulikov gave a general criterion for an abelian $p$-group to be a subgroup of a direct sum of cyclic groups: see Theorems III.17.1 and III.18.1 in the book "Infinite Abelian Groups" by Laszlo Fuchs. This criterion implies that the torsion subgroup of the Cartesian product $\Pi_{n \in \mathbb{N}} C_{p^n}$ cannot be embedded in a direct sum of cyclic groups.